# How does SGP4 work?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, prediction

For calculating orbital state vectors of satellites, SGP4 (simplified perturbations model) is often used in conjunction with [**two-line element sets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) to calculate future positions of orbiting objects. What are the parameters and steps used in the SGP4 method to make these predictions? I am looking for an in depth source about how the model works.

Answer (score 13):

The canonical references are [Spacetrack Report #3](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/documentation/spacetrk.pdf) which is the original documentation of the SGP4 algorithm, and Vallado + Kelso's [Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3](https://celestrak.org/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/AIAA-2006-6753-Rev2.pdf) which has updates, analysis and modern* source code with discussion.

* well, kinda :)

Comment: I also found this AIAA [SGP4 Orbit Determination](http://license.agi.com/downloads/resources/white-papers/SGP4-Orbit-Determination.pdf) (David A. Vallado, PDF) that _"might"_ be fractionally easier to follow. And here's his (commented) [code for C++, FORTRAN, Pascal, and MATLAB](http://www.centerforspace.com/downloads/files/sgp4/AIAA-2006-6753Code.zip) (ZIP), link via [Wiki on SGP/SDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models).

Comment: @TildalWave that is an educational paper too, though it's about turning observations into TLEs rather than turning TLEs into state vectors.

Comment: @TildalWave Did you try to run the Matlab portion of the code? Just tried and it was incomplete. Had to fix a bunch of things to get it to work. Someone should update the Wiki. Update_1: Just found a newer copy of the *.zip file than the one that you have in your link. It comes directly from the website. [Link to code download](http://www.centerforspace.com/downloads/) go to the download and you will see the SGP4 code. Hope this helps. Thanks for the paper reference. Update_2: Found a thesis on this topic [Link for thesis](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1094&cont

Comment: Some of the links @TildalWave mentioned are dead now, but I think this website has the same content he was referencing:
http://www.celestrak.com/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/

Comment: In 2014 this was considered a good answer, but these days it would likely be called "link-only". I wonder if it's possible to augment this with a bit of an answer that does not require the readers to go to those links and read the answer there instead of here?

Comment: After checking all the papers mentioned above, I am wondering if there exists a paper or handbook, that declares the math calculation in the Spacetrack Report #3, because it only lists the formular. I know it's all about orbit mechanics, but putting the principles and calculations together is better to understand the SGP4 algorithm.

Comment: @ROINT  I think the papers you want are Spacetrack #1 and #2, which I'm using in the process of writing a new answer to this question.